# Reading a CSV using R

Tags: r, csv

I have a CSV file that, by all appearances, is totally normal except that each line ends with `,^M`.  Not sure if that has anything to do with my issue or not, but I try reading in the file in R with the usual command

`df <- read.csv('file.csv')`

and then when I try to inspect it by typing `df` it prints out this result that I don't know how to interpret:

```
function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) 
{
    if (missing(ncp)) 
        .External(C_df, x, df1, df2, log)
    else .External(C_dnf, x, df1, df2, ncp, log)
}
<bytecode: 0x000000000b083720>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Anybody know what's going on here?  I've read in CSV files before and had no problem.

Comment: Please refer to this answer to a problem similar to yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843495/what-does-m-character-mean-in-vim

Comment: So I'm not good with VIM and did use the solution on that page, but I opened the file in SublimeText and there it didn't have the `^M` so I saved it like that.  I'm still having the same problem when I try to run this code in R.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, never mind, I just realized that I thought I was running the command to set my working directory to the correct file and it turns out I wasn't so when I was importing the file I was importing the wrong one.  All fixed.

Comment: Glad you realized your mistake 

Can you please mark your answer as accepted, to avoid any more answers :)

Answer (score 0):

The ^M looks like the file came from a computer with a different OS from yours - maybe Unix and you're on Windows? Look on Google for a Unix2DOS utility, or maybe you can open it in Excel and then re-export to fix it.

Comment: Sounds like you're right but I opened it with SublimeText and it didn't have those characters, so I re-saved it without the `^M` and I still have the same problem in R.